# Can you provision users and authenticate in Snowflake using CIAM solutions?

Tags: azure-active-directory, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, google-identity

Snowflake's federation authentication documentation does not explicitly mention Customer Identity Access Management (CIAM):
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/admin-security-fed-auth-overview.html

Is it possible to use CIAM services such as Azure Active Directory B2C or Google Cloud Identity Platform with Snowflake? The idea would be to leverage BYOI / social logins.

Answer (score 1):

We Support SAML and OAUTH. If CIAM supports these standards, then there should not be any issues integrating it with snowflake.
However, this has not been tested from our side.
You can open a support case if you are running into any errors etc.